# compound data filters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, filter, dataset

There must be a way in SSRS to have multiple conditionals for separate data filters?  I have an input report level filter @reportparameter, and data item "Checknum" I need to do something resembling the following:

if @reportparameter = "C" and Left(Fields!Checknum,2) = "NC", filter

otherwise

if @reportparameter = "E" and Left(Fields!Checknum,2) = "VR", then filter

two separate conditionals, both compound statements.

What does the SSRS Dataset look like, as far as syntax?

Comment: The dataset filter depends on what your datasource is and what type of query you use.. and where you want to place the filter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this as part of the query, you could add it to the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (@reportparameter = 'C' and Left(Fields!Checknum,2) = 'NC')
OR (@reportparameter = 'E' and Left(Fields!Checknum,2) = 'VR')
```

But if you want to do it in the dataset filter, your filter **Expression** would be like

```
=IIF((Parameters!reportparameter.Value= "C" AND LEFT(Fields!Checknum.Value, 2) = "NC") 
  OR (Parameters!reportparameter.Value= "E" AND LEFT(Fields!Checknum.Value, 2) = "VR")
     , 1, 0)
```

The type would be **Integer** and the Value would be **1**.

[image]